# Grid layout not centering image W3libary and Bootstrap-4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap 4 and https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/

http://prntscr.com/mtft5t Its not centering in the middle the images So far I tried  `float-left float-right float-none` from bootstrap also used `w3-center` from the w3schools libary but its not centering the image and when I add `margin-right` its ignore it and doenst change the position of the image or div it was in? how do you center the images in the grid ?

grid:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="grid5" class="w3-row-padding w3-padding-64 w3-container">
  <div class="w3-content">
    <div>
      <h1 class="text-center" data-aos="fade-up">Next Step</h1>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row flex-row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="w3-third w3-center">
              <div data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-offset="300" data-aos-easing="ease-in-sine">
                <img src="images/snake.jpg" class="w3-hover-sepia" style="box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px black;width: 18em; height: 18em;" alt="Person">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="w3-third w3-center">
              <div data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-offset="300" data-aos-easing="ease-in-sine">
                <img src="images/snake.jpg" class="w3-hover-sepia" style="box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px black;width: 18em; height: 18em;" alt="Person">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <br>
        <div class="row flex-row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="w3-third w3-center">
              <div data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-offset="300" data-aos-easing="ease-in-sine">
                <img src="images/snake.jpg" class="w3-hover-sepia" style="box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px black;width: 18em; height: 18em;" alt="Person">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="w3-third w3-center">
              <div data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-offset="300" data-aos-easing="ease-in-sine">
                <img src="images/snake.jpg" class="w3-hover-sepia" style="box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px black;width: 18em; height: 18em;" alt="Person">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just replacing `w3-center` with `text-center` worked fine with me ;)

Comment: replacing `w3-center` with `text-center` i tried that but image in the div is center but the divs around it are pushed more to the left even when i added an 'text-center to <div class="container">' its still pushed to the left of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div class="w3-third w3-center">` had to be `<div class="w3-center">` it was making a grid in the grid so it pushed everything to the left and made a little empty space on the right that`s why the images where not centered.

Answer (score 0):

you can add the `<center> </ center>` tag before the parent `<div>` tag

```html
<html>
<body>
<center>
  <div>
  ...
  </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add 'text-center' class to .col div
    eg:
    
    `<div class='row'>
     <div class='col text-center'></div>
    </div>`

    note: 
    * Here text-center is bootstrap class.

Comment: See exactly where u want him to put "text-center" and where i told him to put, u said him to put text-center to direct child of ".col" div t.i in the place of w3-center, where as i said to put text-center beside "col" class, u require minimum basic education to understand the difference broh. u r not the only one who knows css.